# Is this a necessary and sufficient condition for the derivative to exist at $C$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Suppose we want to prove that the derivative of a function across an interval exists at $C$, but the derivative at $C$ cannot be found. We know the function must be continuous. Can we take the limit of derivative from the negative and positive direction of $C$ and show that if they are equal, the derivative at $C$ exists and is equal to the limit obtained? Is this a necessary and sufficient condition?

EDIT:

Sufficiency - If a function is a derivative along some interval, it does not have a *[removable singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity)* at $C$.

Necessity - There is no interval of a derivative of some function in which a jump or [*essential discontinuity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) occurs.

There are two  cases in which the condition is met if this is a necessary and sufficient condition. One is where the derivative is continuous, the other is where there is a *removable discontinuity* in the derivative. Is the latter possible?

Comment: no of course not. I'm asking about the limit of the derivative. Not the limit of $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$

Comment: @gebra Are you asking about $C^1$ functions?  If the limit of the derivative to exists at a point, it is then continuous at the point.  If the derivative is discontinuous, then your original function was not continuously differentiable

Comment: Yes, it is sufficient (Im not sure if necessary) because the unique kind of discontinuities of the derivative of a real function are essential discontinuities. Said in other form: a derivative doesnt have jump discontinuities, hence if the lateral limits are defined then they are equal and the derivative at this point is this limit.

Comment: @n.m. It doesn't seem that way to me. Just to be clear on what not necessary means. Take some continuous function whose derivative approaches different values from different directions at $C$. Now you're saying there exists some function of this form such that at $C$, the derivative exists.

Comment: @Masacroso hmm, I think one of us is confused here. (Probably me) but your statement shows that it is necessary. It doesn't say anything about sufficiency

Comment: @gebra by sufficient I mean that $$\text{lateral limits of derivative exists}\implies \text{derivative exists}$$ and by necessary $$\text{lateral limits of derivative exists}\impliedby \text{derivative exists}$$ I see now that probably this last implication (necessity) is not true because a function can be differentiable at a unique point (at least for functions with domain in $\Bbb C$, not sure if this hold for functions in $\Bbb R$) so there is no laterals limits. Anyway Im not sure if this empty condition is a negation.

Comment: @gebra I misread the problem statement

Comment: A derivative cannot have jumps (Darboux's theorem). Thus if a derivative exists across an interval, and there are one-sided limits at point $x_0$, then (a) they are equal and (b) they are both equal to the value at $x_0$.

Comment: @Masacroso A derivative can exist and be discontinuous at *every* point of an interval.

Comment: @n.m. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444138/differentiable-functions-such-that-the-derivative-is-nowhere-continuous) says the opposite.

Comment: @Masacroso my mistake; I thought of a derivative that has many discontinuities (a dense set), but I see it cannot be discontinuous everywhere.

Comment: Anyway there are differentiable functions with discontinuous derivatives, e.g. $x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}, x \ne 0; 0, x = 0$.

Comment: @n.m. yes. This is enough to see that being differentiable at a point doesnt imply that $f'$ is continuous at this point.

Comment: A derivative *cannot* have jumps but *can* have essential discontinuities.

Answer (score 3):

If the $\lim_{x\to c^+}f^\prime(x)=\ell$ then using the mean value theorem you have that 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=f'(d_x),$$ 
where $c<d_x<x$ and so $d_x\to c$ as $x\to c^+$. Hence, there is
$$\lim_{x\to c^+}\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}=\lim_{x\to c^+}f'(d_x)=\ell.$$
Same for the other side.
So if the limits of the derivatives exist and are equal then $f$ is differentiable. The other implication is false because $f'$ could exist everywhere but not be continuous at $c$.
The function
$f(x)=x^2\sin{1/x}$ if $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$ is differentiable everywhere but the derivative is discontinuous.
Even worse you could take $f(x)=x^2$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. then $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and discontinuous at every other point.

---

**EDIT:** The original question has been modified and so my answer makes no sense anymore. Anyway the derivative of a function is Darboux continuous, so if it cannot have certain types of discontinuities.
[Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))

Comment: wait, can you explain how this shows that the derivative exists at c?

Comment: also i don't really understand the quadratic thing but i'll accept that it is not a necessary condition

Comment: @Masacroso: You have to distinguish between the one-sided limits of ${f(x)-f(c)\over x-c}$ and of $f'(x)$. Note that for the function $f(x):=|x|$ the one-sided limits of $f'(x)$ exist, and are different. The intermediate theorem for derivatives does not apply here since $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: yeah, and the method in my question predicts that $|x|$ doesn't have a derivative at 0. My question is where it actually works. I'm still trying to see how the mean value theorem can actually be used to approach this

Comment: the intermediate value theorem still applies in $[c,x]$ the hypothesis are that $f$ is continuous in $[c,x]$ and differentiable in $(c,x)$. If the limits are different, you get that there exist the left and right derivative at $c$ but they are different, which is the case for $f(x)=|x|$.

Comment: oh, I see. Thank you @Christian, I overlooked this situation.