# Is there a function f : R → R that is continuously differentiable everywhere but twice differentiable nowhere?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let D<sup>n</sup> denote "n times differentiable" and let C<sup>n</sup> denote "n times continuously differentiable".

I'm interested in learning about a counterexample I do not recall ever seeing: a C<sup>1</sup> function

f : ℝ → ℝ

that is D<sup>2</sup> nowhere.

And what about a function g : ℝ → ℝ that is D<sup>2</sup> everywhere but C<sup>2</sup> nowhere?

Comment: Just pick a continuous function which is nowhere differentiable, $f,$ and define $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)\,dt.$$ Then $F'(x)=f(x),$ so $F$ has your property.

Comment: For the first one, take a continuous function $g$ that is nowhere differentiable and consider $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t)\,dt$. The second one is impossible, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444138/differentiable-functions-such-that-the-derivative-is-nowhere-continuous).

Comment: Concerning the first question it suffices to find a continuous function that is nowhere differentiable. Then its antiderivative would satisfy the requirements. Concerning the second question you can do the same trick and reduce the problem of finding $D^1 $ function which is not $C^1$ at every point

Comment: I guess that takes care of both questions!  I've probably seen the first question answered before, but not the second one.